# How to add a user defined field and value to an elasticsearch query

Tags: elasticsearch

Goal: I want a query which adds a discriminator field to distinguish between fuzzy results and non-fuzzy results.

Consider these documents:

```
curl -X POST "localhost:9200/_bulk" -H 'Content-Type: application/json' -d'
{
    "index": {
        "_index": "dishes",
        "_type": "dish",
        "_id": "1"
    }
}
{
    "name": "butter chicken"
}
{
    "index": {
        "_index": "dishes",
        "_type": "dish",
        "_id": "2"
    }
}
{
    "name": "chicken burger"
}

'
```

Consider the following query:

```
curl -X POST "localhost:9200/dishes/_search?pretty" -H 'Content-Type: application/json' -d'
{
    "query": {
        "bool": {
            "should": [
                {
                    "term": {
                        "name": "burger"
                    }
                },
                {
                    "fuzzy": {
                        "name": {
                            "value": "burger"
                        }
                    }
                }
            ],
            "minimum_should_match": 1,
            "boost": 1.0
        }
    }
}
'
```

Can I have a result with an additional tag created during query (it is not in the document) that can be used to discriminate between what is a fuzzy result and what is a non-fuzzy result.

```
...

"hits" : [
    {
      "_index" : "dishes",
      "_type" : "dish",
      "_id" : "2",
      "_score" : 1.3862942,
      "_source" : {
        "name" : "chicken burger"
      },

"is_fuzzy": false

    },
    {
      "_index" : "dishes",
      "_type" : "dish",
      "_id" : "1",
      "_score" : 0.46209806,
      "_source" : {
        "name" : "butter chicken"
      },

"is_fuzzy": true

    }
  ]
```

Scripted fields could have been ideal. But no luck yet.

I have a requirement to present the non-fuzzy results before fuzzy results. So sorting on is_fuzzy and then _score is guaranteed to work. (The actual query is more complex.)

```
       sort: [
            {
                "is_fuzzy": {
                    "order": "desc"
                }
            },
            {
                "_score": {
                    "order": "desc"
                }
            }
```

Comment: This is not necessarily what you asked, but have you considered just giving the exact matches a significant boost so that they will always be ahead of fuzzy matches?

Answer (score 0):

One more option is to use [named queries](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-request-body.html#request-body-search-queries-and-filters) but your `term` filters will need to be slightly reworked:

```
GET dishes/_search
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "should": [
        {
          "term": {
            "name": {
              "value": "burger",
              "_name": "not_fuzzy"
            }
          }
        },
        {
          "fuzzy": {
            "name": {
              "value": "burger",
              "_name": "fuzzy"
            }
          }
        }
      ],
      "minimum_should_match": 1,
      "boost": 1
    }
  }
}
```

yielding

```
[
  {
    "_index":"dishes",
    "_type":"dish",
    "_id":"2",
    "_score":1.3862944,
    "_source":{
      "name":"chicken burger"
    },
    "matched_queries":[         <---
      "fuzzy",
      "not_fuzzy"
    ]
  },
  {
    "_index":"dishes",
    "_type":"dish",
    "_id":"1",
    "_score":0.46209806,
    "_source":{
      "name":"butter chicken"
    },
    "matched_queries":[         <---
      "fuzzy"
    ]
  }
]
```